# Angular Mocks 'module' fails second time it is ran

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write some unit tests for an angular service (factory) that I have created. I can not get my tests to run because the `angular.mock.module` function fails the second time it is called when paired with an `angular.mock.inject` function. I have verified that my tests have nothing to do with these errors as it never gets into my second test and the first test passes fine. The error comes from the `beforeEach` where I re-initialize the angular module I am testing.

Here is my simplified code:

```
// service code
function daEvents ($rootScope) {
  var api = {
    on: function () {}
  };

  return api;
}

daEvents.$inject = ['$rootScope'];

angular.module('test', []).factory('daEvents', daEvents);

// test code
describe('daEvents', function () {
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('test'));

  var daEvents;
  beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function (_daEvents_) {
    daEvents = _daEvents_;
  }));

  it('should exist', function () {
    chai.expect(daEvents).to.exist;
  });

  it('should test ok', function () {
    chai.expect(true).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

and I get this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/ng/areq?p0=fn&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20string
    at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:68:12
    at assertArg (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:1810:11)
    at assertArgFn (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:1820:3)
    at Function.annotate (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:3930:5)
    at Function.angular.injector.$$annotate (:425:187)
    at Object.invoke (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:4626:36)
    at :428:256
    at Object.forEach (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.js:340:20)
    at a.workFn (:428:9)
    at t (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.3.4/mocha.min.js:7:33286)
```

See this JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kvs2fhLd/)

Comment: I admit, this is a nice question, but, I have the very same code in my project and it works perfectly (the only difference is I don't use ngMock as dependency, I have Karma that do that). Whats the actual code of the service? By the way, I use Jasmine

Comment: @Gianmarco I'm using MochaJS + chai. In my Karma setup, I have it add ngMock but the issue is still the same. The code for the service doesn't matter, the error happens no matter what. Maybe it's a mocha issue?

Comment: It might be... I can assure, I have the exact same code to test my service: `beforeEach(module('myModule'));

    var pageService, $loc;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_PageService_, $location) {
        pageService = _PageService_;
        $loc = $location;
    }));`

Comment: the difference is that I declare the var outside before (I am under a 'use strict'). in your case the daEvents var. But I tried your code with the var initialized outside and it's the same.

Comment: It looks like it's a known issue and a fix is in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13397

Comment: thank you for signaling this

Answer (score 2):

It's a known issue and a fix is already in: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13397